# How does VSTO work in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

Few question about VSTO project I don't understand:

1. Registration - unlike native Office Plugin, where I've an installation project, how does the deployment work in managed add-in? After building the project, I do have the necessary entries in the registry that define the plugin (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins...). Where is the code that perform this registration?
2. Also, why in the HKCU? I'd like the plugin to be defined for all users (in HKLM). How do I change that?
3. How does Visual Studio know to start Outlook, when I press F5? In the property page for the project, under the debugging tab, the 'Start Option' is set to 'Start project'. Who tells Visual Studio that starting the project means starting Outlook?
4. Looking for more materials about VSTO. Can you recommend a resource?

Answer (score 0):

A few answers
1. Basically the same for a managed project except that the Reg entries point to the .MANIFEST file, which in turn identifies the dll of the addin assembly.

1. Ohhh. this is a LONG story, there's lots of info on the web about it. Google "registering an addin for all users".
   Short version is that it's possible, but requires some really weird and difficult to explain registry shinanigans.
2. If you've created an Outlook addin property, then by virtue of that project type, VS knows what to do on start.
3. I've never found a good definitive source for vsto material. Google's been my best friend for that kind of info. Andrew Coates has a pretty decent list here though
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acoat/archive/2007/08/02/vsto-resources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have no explicit information but currently I'm working through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx which so far has been a great source of information. Please let me know if this worked out for your Outlook project.